# Create COM object

Tags: windows-server-2008, com

I want to test creating a COM object. Normally I use Excel or Word VBA and add a reference to the DLL I want to test. However I am on a Windows 2008 server without these programs and only the basic software installed that comes with Windows, plus IIS. How can I create a COM object easily and call its properties and methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Powershell.

For example, this creates new Word App com object:
`$word = new-object -com Word.Application`

If you use PS 3+ ISE, it also includes handy Intellisense:
[image]

Full reference here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849885.aspx
And usage here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/%5Clibrary/Dd347574.aspx